# Como adicionar a resposta de uma requisição Axios em um Array?

Tags: array, react, typescript, axios, react-hooks

Estou tentando colocar a resposta de uma requisição Axios dentro de um array, mas estou recebendo como resposta uma estrutura estranha, conforme mostrarei na imagem a seguir:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Criei um Array, adicionei meu próprio nome e logo apos tentei fazer um loop onde eu adiciono os items referentes a resposta da requisição Axios. Mas como resposta eu obtenho essa estrutura da imagem acima, e o mais estranho, quando eu tento acessar da posição 4 para frente, ele me retorna "undefined"
Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Aqui está o código:

```
var nomes: Array<String> = [];
nomes.push("Abner")
nomes.push("Matheus")
nomes.push("Gomes")
nomes.push("Silva")
mat.map(r => {
  Axios.get(`/pessoal/pessoa/${r}/buscarCursos`).then(response => {
     nomes.push(response.data.toString())
  })
})
console.log(nomes)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pelo seu código, tirando a função toString e colocando algum atributo-field que retorna do axios, ele irá adicionar o retorno dentro do array nomes, dando sequência. Após "Silva", vem a quantidade de iteração em mat, se tiver um array com 10 itens, ele irá retornar a field dos 10 somando 14 itens, contando em array será 13 porque começa no 0.

Se quiser retornar as matérias do lado do nome dos alunos, utiliza o Object.

```
const mat = ['6e66784-0e1c-cf1-6708-848c66518f6f', '2bdcedb-c25a-3f1e-443e-b6a2463d856']

let nomes = Array()
nomes.push('abner')
nomes.push('matheus')

mat.map(item => {
  axios.get(`http://localhost:3333/projects/${item}`).then(response => {
    Object.assign(nomes, { materia: response.data.name })
    console.log(nomes)
  })
})
```